# SQL Sub Query within a join

Tags: sql

Is there a difference between the results of the two sets of code below?

If there isn't, I don't understand why my teachers keep teaching sub queries. When would they be useful in basic SQL commands?

```
Select soh.Total, c.*
From SalesLT.Customer As c
Inner join (select oh.CustomerID Sum(oh.TotalDue) As Total
From SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader As oh Group by oh.CustomerID
Having Sum(oh.totaldue) > 90000) As soh on c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
```

VS

```
Select A.*, C.*
From Sales as A inner join Customer as C on A.customerID=C.customerID
Group by A.CustomerID
Having Sum(C.totaldue) > 90000
```

Comment: The first query you are pulling the `Total`, the second one you aren't.  Also, the second query is not valid syntax because of the `GROUP BY` statement not having all non-aggregated columns included in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Did you try running both of the queries against your data source? They seem to be selecting different columns. In fact, the second query uses a table named "Sales", but the first one uses "SalesOrderHeader". Are those the same?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a difference?  Well, obviously.  The two are constructed differently.

Do they produce the same result?  Obviously not.  In fact, the second one will produce an error in almost all databases, because the columns from `A` are not aggregated.

In addition, the number of columns is likely to differ between the two queries, unless `Customer` has exactly two columns.

I would suggest that you study SQL a bit harder.  If your teachers are suggesting that you need to understand subqueries, then that is probably because they are an important part of the language.

Homework:  Write a reasonable second query that doesn't use subqueries.

Comment: You said write a reasonable second query that doesn't use subquery. If I had changed the "having sum(C.totaldue) > 90000" to "having sum(A.totaldue) > 90000" since I grouped by using the A table, would that fix it? I'm sorry if I seem like I don't know a lot. I've been studying hours upon hours each day and I am having trouble with this language.

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries always took more time in term of performance and return results.
Where as inner joins provide faster way to fetch results and process queries.

So this is always good to user inner joins and avoid sub queries as much as possible, it effect execution time. To test more, try to add Execution Plan before running query in query panel.

This will show you difference of results and time took to execute.